Why is vertically polarized light preferentially refracted at the surface and horizontally polarized light preferentially reflected?
I was reading OpenStax Physics on the topic of polarisation and Brewster's angle but there was no clear explanation as to why vertically polarised light generally refracts while horizontally polarised light generally is reflected of a surface. Is there a simple yet intuitive way to understand this (this topic is still very new to me)?

See Fresnel equations, and consider matching conditions across boundaries for the fields.

It's boundary conditions. The normal component of the displacement field is continuous across the boundary. One polarization state has the electric field orthogonal to the surface normal (in plane, so to speak), while the other polarization is orthogonal to that and $\vec k$, so it has an angle dependent projection onto the surface normal, giving both polarization and angle dependence.
You need to write down incident wave plus refracted wave plus reflected wave, and ensure all their $E$ fields at the surface satisfy the boundary conditions.
(I don't recall if you need to do the same for magnetic fields...maybe that's only for $\mu\ne\mu_0$).
